# The caller's YouTube account is not connected to Google+

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

good day

I'm using the API explorer at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22snippet%22%3A%7B%22videoId%22%3A%22s-VhIdn0q5E%22%2C%22topLevelComment%22%3A%7B%22snippet%22%3A%7B%22textOriginal%22%3A%22Tsssssnt%20thread.%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D

to test this call. I am requesting the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl.

Code connect:

```
    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = idapp.ToString();
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(client_secret_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                 GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                 new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl},userid, ct).Result;
    }
    youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        ApiKey = apikey,
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = idapp.ToString()
                    });
```

RESPONSE:

```
    cache-control: private
    content-encoding: gzip
    content-length: 204
    content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    date: Mon, 29 Jun 2020 13:07:32 GMT
    server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
    vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
    
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller's YouTube account is not connected to Google+.",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "The caller's YouTube account is not connected to Google+.",
            "domain": "youtube.commentThread",
            "reason": "ineligibleAccount",
            "location": "Authorization",
            "locationType": "header"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

In apps Exception  like this:

## Exception Text

> The service youtube has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
> The caller's YouTube account is not connected to Google+. [403]
> Errors [
> Message[The caller's YouTube account is not connected to Google+.] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[ineligibleAccount] Domain[youtube.commentThread]
> ]
> at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.d__31.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Google account was created a week ago. Please help how to use api to add comments on youtube via c # application

```
public bool Comment(string Channel_Id, string Video_Id, string commentmsg)
    {
        try
        {
            CommentThreadSnippet commentThreadSnippetz = new CommentThreadSnippet();
            commentThreadSnippetz.ChannelId = Channel_Id;
            commentThreadSnippetz.VideoId = Video_Id;
            commentThreadSnippetz.TopLevelComment = new Comment() { Snippet = new CommentSnippet() { TextOriginal = commentmsg } };
            CommentThreadsResource.InsertRequest commentReq = youtubeService.CommentThreads.Insert(new CommentThread() { Snippet = commentThreadSnippetz }, "snippet");
            CommentThread commentRes = commentReq.Execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var f in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                MessageTip.ShowError(f.Message, 5000);
            }
            coonector = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in old account its working

Comment: Please edit your question and included your authorization code.

Comment: The connection works and I get statistics data. But I can’t add comments

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's actually too late, but for anyone else encountering this problem, your account that you're trying to use is google only - it has no associated youtube CHANNEL. Just login in on youtube, click your profile pic and create a channel. Worked for me.